# iphone sdk: Cropping Image using BJImageCropper - Not gets Center Aligned

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using `BJImageCropper` in one of my iPhone apps.

I select picture from Photo Library and crop it using your cropper classes.

The problem I am facing is that I want to center align `BJImageCropper`. But it always get skewed to left side. And its frame is always different depending upon the image selected.

So at times, it comes in middle. At times it goes to extreme left. Is there anyway to center align it.

Comment: Please can you add code of what you have tried so far so that people can try to help

Comment: I was using an older version of BJImageCropper. Redownloaded the fresh copy and it started working fine.